# MVC5 post to controller without leaving page

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm building an MVC5 application (using Razor). In the nav bar at the top, I have a button that fades in a form used for feedback. I'm able to successfully post this data to a different controller (rather than the one currently generating the page), however I can't make the page NOT load the post method of the controller. I can have it reload the current page, but I want to prevent any screen changes. Is this possible?

I tried using [an AJAX method](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/jquery-ajax-get-and-post-calls-to-controllers-method-in-mvc/) to accomplish this, but it didn't work.

Here is my current code in the view:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="feedbackForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="feedbackFormLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h5 class="modal-title">Feedback for @ViewBag.Title</h5>
            </div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateRemote", "Feedback", FormMethod.Post)) {
                <div class="modal-body">

                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pain)
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pain, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pain, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <input id="FeedbackSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

This is how I modified the end of it to use AJAX:

```
@*@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateRemote", "Feedback", FormMethod.Post)) {*@
    <div class="modal-body">

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pain)
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pain, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pain, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <input id="FeedbackSubmit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#FeedbackSubmit').click(function () {
                var url = "/Feedback/CreateRemote";
                var pain = 10;
                $.post(url, { LanId: 'C15919' }, function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                });
            })
        </script>
    </div>
@*}*@
```

If I leave the `input` as is, no action is taken, and the controller is not invoked. if I change it to `<input type="submit" ....`, then the page is changed to the POST action of the controller.

Comment: You can accomplish that with AJAX.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. However, I'm not too familiar with AJAX, so I might have been doing it wrong.

Comment: AJAX is an appropriate technology to use if you want to post data to the back end without refreshing the page. Update your code to show your attempt at AJAX. The code you now show will do a normal HTTP post, so is not helpful to answering your question.

Comment: You should put in how you tried it with AJAX.

Comment: I edited the post to show what I've tried.

Comment: If you included the js without removing the FormHelper / changing the button type from submit.  It was still treating it as a normal form submit.  If you change the button type, I bet it will work, but you'll want to clean up your form more than that.

Comment: I removed the form helper, but it's still not working.

Comment: You still haven't shown how you're using AJAX. You just commented out your form.

Comment: Maybe this is part of my confusion, because I thought the code in between the `script` tag was AJAX. I was using (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/jquery-ajax-get-and-post-calls-to-controllers-method-in-mvc/) as a reference in trying to develop this solution, but it's not working. Is there another reference you can point me towards?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using type="button" for the submit button and also use the ajax call as below:

```
var p = { Data: $('#search').val() };

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Feedback/CreateRemote",
        data: JSON.stringify(p),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
});
```